# How to hide/show text field in swift using a switch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

Question 1. How can I use a switch to hide/show a text field in Swift?

Question 2. How can I make the text field area be hidden and shown dynamically?
btw: I'm working on Swift storyboard.

My problem was caused by a hidden object, and it was solved after deleting it.
Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

First take Outlet of textfield. Then show and hide textfield on switch's ON & OFF State.

Comment: Can you please show me an example? I could not find any on the internet

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBOutlet weak var stateSwitch:  UISwitch!
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()     
    stateSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
}

func stateChanged(switchState: UISwitch) {
    //Single line code
    //textField.isHidden = !switchState.isOn

    //Multi line code
    if switchState.isOn {
       textField.isHidden = false
    } else {
        textField.isHidden = true
    }
}
```